# Why tf.pad return shape [?,?,?]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried do some customized padding before feeding to a conv1D net as following.

```
x=tf.placeholder("float",[None,50,1])

padding=tf.constant([0,0],[5,0],[0,0])

y=tf.pad(x,padding)
```

However, after the above manipulation, y would be a tensor of shape (?,?,?), thus when feeding to tf.layers.conv1d, I get an error that "The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found 'None'".

My question is why does pad result has None shape? It should not be hard to calculate the shape, my guess is this is only calculated in run time, but it is not convenient right? And can I use reshape before passing to conv1d?

Comment: Except for a potential typo in your `padding` (which should be `padding=tf.constant([0,0],[5,0],[0,0])`), I don't have any problems running `z = tf.layers.conv1d(y, 8, 2)` after your three lines. My tensorflow-gpu is 1.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I too found it worked, thought I don't know what originally went wrong. And there is a typo, just to avoid misleading anyone, padding should be padding=tf.constant([[0,0],[5,0],[0,0]])